# How to convert a char array containing double value to double variable?

Tags: java, double, arrays

Sorry, if I am not posting my try. I have no idea how to approach this.

I want charArr to be converted to doubleVal:

```
char[] charArr = {'1'','1','.','1','1','1'};
double doubleVal = 11.11;
```

Comment: Hint: convert the array to a string, then parse the `double` value.

Comment: You really need to learn the basics.  Refer to a tutorial, a basic one can be found by searching for _java nuts and bolts_.

Comment: Sorry I am a C guy and had to quickly do a stuff.                `String s = new String(charArr);
Double doubleval = Double.parseDouble(s);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a hint

- convert the char array to string. ( see String.valueOf method)
- convert the string to double value ( see Double.parseDouble)

Comment: I do this `s = String.valueOf(charArr);` and let's suppose charArr has {'1', ' ',' '}. I set breakpoint after s has been set and I find that s has "1 . I see an extra " in front of the 1. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(charArr);
Double d = Double.parseDouble(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that: you can try this

```
for(int i=0; i<charArr.length;i++){
char c =charArr[i];
Double d = Double.parseDouble(c.toString());
// do some operation
}
```