# How to convert a char array containing double value to double variable, WITHOUT creating overhead of String object?

Tags: java, string, parsing, double

My question is in line with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23026392/how-to-convert-a-char-array-containing-double-value-to-double-variable), but I need to do this without creating any overhead.

The native `parseDouble()` in java takes in a string, but my situation gives me a buffer of raw memory I can access via `buf.getByte(int position)`. Since my use case processes hundreds of thousands of such doubles at a time, it is clunky and slow to create a new String for each one.

Therefore, I need a way to go from the byte representation of a double (buffer holding chars/bytes representing {'1' '1' '.' '1'} for 11.1) to a Double, without creating additional objects on the heap while doing so.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: You can parse an entire `char[]` at a time with `Double.valueOf(new String(c));` where `c` is your `char[]`, but that still creates an intermediate `String`.

Comment: @GBlodgett Yeah that's the issue, I need to do this without creating any intermediate objects on heap. primitives are obviously okay.

Answer (score 1):

Crude, hacky and won't work with negatives but you can do the legwork to shore it up:

```
private static double toDouble(byte[] bs) {
    boolean onLeft = true;
    double left = 0;
    double right = 0;

    for (byte b : bs) {
        if (b == '.') {
            onLeft = false;
        } else if (onLeft) {
            left *= 10;
            left += b - '0';
        } else {
            right += b - '0';
            right /= 10;
        }
    }

    return left + right;
}
```

And:

```
 System.out.println(toDouble(new byte[] { '1', '1', '.', '1' }));
```

Yields 11.1.

Comment: +1, if you know something special about the data in question, use it, because the JDK has to handle everything - https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/6bab0f539fba8fb441697846347597b4a0ade428/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/math/FloatingDecimal.java ends up creating an intermediate converter object to help

Answer (score 0):

Something in the lines of the other answer,

```
public static double arr2double(char[] arr) {
double num = 0;
double num2 = 0;
int idForDot=arr.length;
boolean isNeg = false;
char[] st =  null;
int start = 0;
int end = arr.length;
boolean hasDot=false;

if (arr[0] == '-') {
    isNeg = true;
    start++;
} else if (arr[0] == '+') 
    start++;

for(int i = start; i < arr.length; i++)
  if (arr[i] == '.') {
      hasDot=true;
      idForDot=i;
      for (int j = arr.length - 1; j >= idForDot + 1; j--)
          num2 = (num2 + arr[j] - '0') / 10;
      break;
  } 

  if (hasDot)
    st = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, idForDot);
  else 
      st = arr;

for (int i = start; i < st.length; i++) {
    if (st[i] == ',')
        continue;
    num *= 10;
    num += st[i] - '0';
}
num = num + num2;
if (isNeg)
    num = -1 * num;

return num;
```

}